# Problems with rx-android java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, android, rx-android

I am using rx java with android and my event bus class is as below

```
public class EventBus {
private final Subject<Event, Event> subject = new SerializedSubject<>(PublishSubject.<Event>create());
private Observable<Map<Type, Event>> stickyObservable;

public EventBus() {
    createStickyObservable();
}

private void createStickyObservable() {
    final List<Observable<Event>> observables = new ArrayList<>();

    final Observable<Map<Type, Event>> so = subject
            .filter(event -> event.sticky)
            .groupBy(event -> event.type)
            .switchMap(groupedObservable -> {
                BehaviorSubject<Event> bs = BehaviorSubject.create();
                groupedObservable.subscribe(bs);
                observables.add(bs);
                return Observable.combineLatest(observables, args -> {
                    Map<Type, Event> map = new HashMap<>();
                    for (Object arg : args) {
                        Event event = (Event) arg;
                        map.put(event.type, event);
                    }

                    return map;
                });
            });

    final BehaviorSubject<Map<Type, Event>> bs = BehaviorSubject.create();
    so.subscribe(bs);
    stickyObservable = bs;
}

public Observable<Event> filter(final String pathExpression) {
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(pathExpression);

    return subject.filter(event -> {
        if (event.path == null) {
            return pathExpression == null;
        }
        return pattern.matcher(event.path).matches();
    });
}

public Observable<Map<Type, Event>> getStickyObservable() {
    return stickyObservable;
}


public void event(Event event) {
    subject.onNext(event);
}
}
```

Some time my application crashing with

```
rx.internal.operators.OperatorSwitch$SwitchSubscriber
```

When i inspected the issue it seems like there is a

```
 java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError on the OperatorSwitch with 
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: state
```

Comment: Are you sure your rxjava versions are the latest ones? Can you post your `build.gradle` file?

Comment: @wasyl compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1'

Comment: Is this your whole gradle file? You can update question with whole one

Comment: unable to update gradle on the question
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1'

Comment: Try this http://nerds.weddingpartyapp.com/tech/2014/12/24/implementing-an-event-bus-with-rxjava-rxbus/